# Almost Sure Convergence of a product with SLLN

Tags: probability, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

This is an exam problem, so it should be rather easy but I still can't quite see how to solve it:

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independent and identically distributed random variables on the same probability space such that 
$$ \mathbb{P} \left[ X_1 = - \frac14 \right] = \mathbb{P} \left[ X_1 = \frac14 \right] = \frac12.$$
For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define 
$$ M_n := \prod_{k=1}^n (1+X_k).$$
Use the law of large numbers to show that $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges almost surely and determine the limit.

(It might be worth noting that the first part was to show that $(M_n)_n$ is a martingale.)

The naive way to apply the SLLN is by taking $\log$ and then naively using SLLN. However, I can only get the limit of $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+X_k)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ in this way. So what's the correct way of applying the law of large numbers?

Comment: Not sure why proving martingale helps but the limit of what you got which is $E(\log(1+X_k))$ should be negative. Hence $\sum \log(1+X_k) \to -\infty$. Taking exponential, $M_n \to 0$.

Comment: Oh. Okay, I was stupid, I thought $\mathbb{E}[\log(1+X_k)] = 1$. That clears up things - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James Tang pointed out
$$
\mathbb{E}[\log(1+X_k)]=\frac12\log\Big(\frac{15}{16}\big)<0
$$

By SLN, 
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{k=1}\log(1+X_k)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{15}{16}\Big)
$$
almost surely (and in $L_1(\mathbb{P})$. A simple argument the shows that 
for $\mathbb{P}$--a.s all points $\omega\in\Omega$, there us $N=N(\omega)$ such that 
for all $n\geq N$
$$
\sum^n_{k=1}\log\big(1+X_k(\omega)\big)\leq \frac{1}{4}\log\Big(\frac{15}{16}\Big)n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}-\infty
$$
which means that $\prod^\infty_{n=1}(1+X_n)=0$ $\mathbb{P}$--a.s.

Comment: Thank you for writing it out (but it was already more than clear with James Yang‘s pointer).